# What does indeterministic behavior means?

Tags: java, clone

I saw this term used a lot in [Joshua block's book](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) effective java specialy on the item related to the method clone , so can some explain what does it means and examples of it ?

Thanks.

Comment: The term is NON-deterministic, not indeterministic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeterministic, or usually non-deterministic, system is a system that is not deterministic. Deterministic is described in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_system) as:

> > In mathematics [and computer science], a deterministic system is a system in which no randomness is involved in the development of future states of the system. A deterministic model will thus always produce the same output from a given starting condition or initial state.

In other words, non-deterministic system is one where there is no guarantee same input will always produce same output.

Comment: "indeterministic system is one where there is no guarantee same input will always produce same output".. thank you for that line :)

Answer (score 4):

indeterministic means literally you cannot determine what the outcome will be.

Thread safety bugs are the most common example of indeterministic behaviour.

http://www.google.com/search?q=thread+safety+examples ~ 4M results.

Answer (score 0):

Practically, non-deterministic means that when you run a program multiple times with the same inputs, the outputs may differ.

For the clone method, I don't know, I don't have the book, sorry.